# OpenCV Recorded webcam-video is faster than real life Python

Tags: python, opencv, video, real-time, webcam

I am reaching some problems recording my video from the webcam. Because I am doing an experiment and at the same time recording the video, it is very important that the real second is the same as the second recorded.
The code I am using is this one:

```
def record_video(self, path_video="test"):
    vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #vid_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20)
    fps=vid_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    #vid_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 2)
    vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    output = cv2.VideoWriter("experiment_videos/" + path_video + ".avi", vid_cod, fps, (640,480))
    x = threading.Thread(target=socket_trigger)
    x.daemon = True
    x.start()
    print("Waiting")
    while(start==0):
        ret_cam, frame_cam = vid_capture.read()
    while (True):
        ret_cam, frame_cam = vid_capture.read()
        output.write(frame_cam)
            # Close and break the loop after pressing "x" key
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('x'):
            break
        if end== 1:
            break
    # close the already opened camera
    vid_capture.release()
    #cap.release()
    # close the already opened file
    output.release()
    # close the window and de-allocate any associated memory usage
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

All code works, the flag variables that I receive work properly. The problem comes when, for instance, if I record a video of 5 mins (real time), the output can be 4:52,4:55 or even 5:00. It's just not exact.

I think it's because I write in a output file of 30fps (that's what `vid_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS`) returns) and my camera sometimes is recording in less frames(let's say `28,29`).

I don't know what to do, I have tried setting fps of the cameras at 20 but it didn't work (`#vid_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20)`).

Any ideas? For me is so critical matching times, and my only job is to record a webcam camera.
Thanks for all,
Jaime

Comment: try to measure the achieved fps (counter/seconds) and after finishing, open the vid, read it and create a new one with the right fps.

Comment: But this has some disadvatanges: the resulting real fps may be a float. if I want a int (let's say 28fps and I got 28.3fps), I have to discard frames along the video, in this case 1 frame each 3 seconds. That's not trivial from my point of view. Any suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: use a video format with timestamp information and an imaging library that supports it